# Mixing thymeleaf and jsp files in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Is there anyway to use plain jsp files without a controller mixed with thymeleaf views using controllers in Spring Boot/MVC?

For example, a standard controller is as follows;

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String get() {
    return "view";
}
```

Which works exactly as expected, but is it possible to map ".jsp" files put in a folder to any url for example test.jsp would go to www.website.com/test.jsp

Regards.

Comment: I tried, in a project jsp and thymeleaf can not coexist, as I would like to use jsp must comment out **Spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf** depend on the package, so that it can run. Spring boot the official website is not recommended to use jsp template. This is my test, if not please understand.

Comment: Look at this article：https://github.com/AndyCZY/czy-study-spring-boot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following configuration in `servlet-context.xml` (the contextConfigLocation of the DispatcherServlet):

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="jsp/*"></beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order" value="1"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Thymeleaf -->
<beans:bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    <!-- This narrows the scope of the resolver to the view names (returned 
        by the controllers' methods) to those matching the pattern -->
    <beans:property name="viewNames" value="templates/*"></beans:property>
    <!-- places this resolver before the default InternalResourceViewResolver -->
    <beans:property name="order" value="0"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateResolver"
    class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Thymeleaf _ end -->
```

In order to render the response with a JSP, in the controller I return a string like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {

    return "jsp/home";
}
```

whereas to render with a thymeleaf template, I do the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getRanks(Model model, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return "templates/user/ranks";
}
```

Of course, the physical location of the `.jsp` and `.html` files must match the view name returned by the controllers. So, according to how the resolvers are configured, you will have to place `.jsp` files inside `/views/jsp` and `.html` files (for thymeleaf) inside `/views/templates`

If you want a url like `www.website.com/test.jsp` to be rendered with the `test.jsp` view, you can simply put the aformentiond jsp file inside the root directory of your webapp. The request should be resolved by the JSP servlet, if no strange configuration is in place. In fact, a servlet container like Tomcat normally have this specification in its global `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

and

```
<!-- The mappings for the JSP servlet -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

If you want something more customized and specific, you will have to modify your configuration accordingly. For example, remove the JSP servlet from you servlet container's web.xml and map *.jsp url in the appropriate controllers