# Coexistence of both thymeleaf and jasper files in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports, thymeleaf, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-starter

I tried, in a project both jasper and thymeleaf, but can not coexist, as I would like to use jsp must comment out Spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf depend on the package, so that it can run. Looking for a solution so that both jasper and thymeleaf can co exist. I got a solution on stackoverflow if some one use servlet-context.xml ( [Mixing thymeleaf and jsp files in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985798/mixing-thymeleaf-and-jsp-files-in-spring-boot) ), where both jasper and thymeleaf coexist. But my requirement is how to include those attributes in pom.xml if I am using spring-boot-starter-web.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run both HTML and JSP page from embedded jar build inside Spring boot. But if you like to run it independently by copying the Jar in command prompt then you need to copy the JSP page folder structure as it will not be in the jar content and you need to change the pom file little bit so that the jar can add external content to it.

STEP 1: Add Thymeleaf and JSP dependencies 
Add below dependencies to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

STEP 2: Project structure and file creation

Under source folder src/main/resources create folder templates, under that create sub-folder thymeleaf. And create a html file sample.html(say)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  THYMELEAF PAGE: <p th:text="${name}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF create sub-folder views. Under views create a jsp file, sample.jsp(say)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
   JSP PAGE: Hello ${name}
</body>
</html>
```

STEP 3: In your application.properties set thymeleaf view names and JSP configuration for internal view resolution.

```
#tomcat-connection settings
spring.datasource.tomcat.initialSize=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=25
#Jasper and thymeleaf configaration
spring.view.prefix= /WEB-INF/
spring.view.suffix= .jsp
spring.view.view-names= views
spring.thymeleaf.view-names= thymeleaf
#Embedded Tomcat server 
server.port = 8080
#Enable Debug
debug=true
management.security.enabled=false
```

STEP 4: Create controller for serving Thymeleaf and JSP pages:

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/jasper", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newjasper(Map<String, Object> m, String name){
        //System.out.print("-- INSIDE JSP CONTROLER ------");
        m.put("name", name);
        return "views/sample";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/thymeleaf", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newthymeleaf(Map<String, Object> m, String name){
        //System.out.print("-- INSIDE HTML CONTROLER ------");
        m.put("name", name);
        return "thymeleaf/sample";
    } 

}
```

STEP 5: Some cases you may required to create a configuration class SpringConfig.class (say) for view resolution for JSP pages. But optional, I don't use it in my configuration file.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
public class SpringConfig {
@Value("${spring.view.prefix}")
private String prefix;

@Value("${spring.view.suffix}")
private String suffix;

@Value("${spring.view.view-names}")
private String viewNames;

@Bean
InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    final InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new 
    InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix(prefix);
    viewResolver.setSuffix(suffix);
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setViewNames(viewNames);
    return viewResolver;
 }
}
```

STEP 6: Testing application for both jsp and html.

When you hit this url in your browser: http://localhost:8080/thymeleaf?name=rohit . This will open our sample.html file with parameter name in center of page and with this url: http://localhost:8080/jasper?name=rohit will open sample.jsp page with parameter name in center.

Answer (score 0):

from the viewresover javadoc.

> Specify a set of name patterns that will applied to determine whether
>   a view name returned by a controller will be resolved by this resolver
>   or not.
>
> In applications configuring several view resolvers –for example, one
>   for Thymeleaf and another one for JSP+JSTL legacy pages–, this
>   property establishes when a view will be considered to be resolved by
>   this view resolver and when Spring should simply ask the next resolver
>   in the chain –according to its order– instead.
>
> The specified view name patterns can be complete view names, but can
>   also use the * wildcard: "index.*", "user_*", "admin/*", etc.
>
> Also note that these view name patterns are checked before applying
>   any prefixes or suffixes to the view name, so they should not include
>   these. Usually therefore, you would specify orders/* instead of
>   /WEB-INF/templates/orders/*.html.
>
> Specify names of views –patterns, in fact– that cannot be handled by
>   this view resolver.
>
> These patterns can be specified in the same format as those in
>   setViewNames(String []), but work as an exclusion list. 
>   viewResolver.setViewNames(viewNames);